# How to specify the specific elements in order - using util ordering in Alloy?

Tags: alloy

My intention here is to specify Date in order. Start with d, followed by d1, d2, d3, and end with d". I have initialised 'd = request.begin' as the first element while 'd"' as the last element in the ordering. In the following codes, I define 'd1 = d.next', 'd2 = d1.next', and, 'd3 = d2.next'. In addition, I invoked util ordering in the library; 'open util/ordering [Date] as DateOrder'. However, no instance found when executing the codes. Could anyone please let me know what's the problem with the codes?

```
    open util/ordering [Date] as DateOrder

    abstract sig resource {}

    one sig  Tour  extends resource  {date : one Date, destination :  tour_destination}
    one sig tour_destination {}

    pred holiday [disjoint d,d1,d2,d3,d": some Date , r:Request, t:Tour] {
    r.begin = d and r.end = d" 
    t.date = d or t.date = d1 or t.date = d2 or t.date = d3 or t.date = d"
    d != d"}

    sig Date{}

    pred init [d:Date]{d= Request.begin}

    fact traces {
    init [first] 
    let d" = last   | one d : Date - last |
     let d1 = d.next, d2 = d1.next, d3 = d2.next |
       lone t: Tour, r: Request|
          holiday [d,d1,d2,d3,d",r,t]}

    one sig Request{tour_request: one Tour,begin: one Date, end: one Date}


    run holiday
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't necessarily a problem. The given code might be fine, but the model it represents might be inconsistent (thus Alloy cannot find any instance). Note that since you did not presented the full model, neither enough details of which predicate are you running, this answer tries to guess what might be wrong.

It seems that the statement

```
one d: Date - last
```

causes the inconsistency for you. Note that, due to the import of ordering, such statement might be consistent only for universes that have 2 instances of the Date signature.

As an example, if `one` is replaced by `some`, Alloy finds a lot of instances for the following model:

```
open util/ordering [Date]

sig Request{
    begin: lone Date
}

sig Date{}

pred init [d:Date]{d= Request.begin}

fact traces {
  init [first] 
  let d" = last | some d : Date - last |
  let d1 = d.next, d2 = d1.next, d3 = d2.next |
  d1 in Date && d2 in Date && d3 in Date && d" in Date
}

run {} for 4 but 1 Request
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments @ivcha. I have made a change as per suggested. However, there is a syntax error: The name " d" " cannot be found. The updated codes can be seen in the question section above. Is there something wrong in the model?

Comment: In the updated version shows that the begin date of holiday is Request.begin = d, the end date of holiday is Request.end, while the tour date can be either same date as the begin date d, or the date after d, d1, or d2, or d3, or same as the end date of holiday d".

Comment: In the future, another date for transport will be added. Let say, d is begin date of holiday, d1 is transport date (e.g. train), d2 is tour date, d3 is transport date for bus, and d" is end date of holiday. I would really appreciated if you could give some advice for this matter. Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't get "syntax error: The name " d" " cannot be found" for either of the models (so I presume you fixed the error). My answer should give you enough insight to fix your particular model. Also, try to play with different parameters of run. (I think you should try to fix your model or create another question if you have other specific issue.)

Comment: Yes, the answer is helpful for me. However if I added a suggested code " d1 in Date && d2 in Date && d3 in Date && d" in Date" the syntax error came out: The name " d" " cannot be found.

Comment: I copy pasted your code (into the code from my answer) and I don't get that error...